# How can I successfully edit in my update php code?

Tags: php, edit

I'm looking for solution on how to edit the inside of my modal -the title and the note. Below is my code, I want to edit inside the button which is in modal. After successfully updated the data, I want to display the updated data by calling the homepage (hh.php) which is in my code.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
         $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","task");
         $qi=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM note WHERE id = ".$_GET['id']);

         while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qi)){
            $tit = $row['title'];
            $not = $row['note'];
         }
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
body
{
    margin:0;
}
.submitted{
margin:0px;
}
.modal
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    display:none;
}
.modal_close
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
.close
{
    cursor:pointer;
}
.note{
text-align:center;
}
#note{
font-family: Javanese text;
}
.call_modal{
 font-family: myFirstFont;
}
.modal_main
{
    width:50%;
    height:400px;
    background:#fff;
    z-index:4;
    position:fixed;
    top:16%;
    border-radius:4px;
    left:24%;
    display:none;
 -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .0s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: visible!important;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInRight;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight{0%{opacity:0;-webkit-transform:translateX(20px)}100%{opacity:1;-webkit-transform:translateX(0)}}
::-webkit-input-placeholder{
  font-size: 13.4px;
}
button
{
padding:20px;
border-radius:5px;
background:#808080;
border:none;
font-size:18px;
color:#fff;
margin:8%;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".call_modal").click(function(){
    $(".modal").fadeIn();
    $(".modal_main").show();
      });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".close").click(function(){
    $(".modal").fadeOut();
    $(".modal_main").fadeOut();
      });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".submitted").click(function(){
    $(".modal").fadeOut();
    $(".modal_main").fadeOut();
      });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="call_modal" style="cursor:pointer;"> Edit Task </button>
<div class="modal">
<div class="modal_close close"></div>
<div class="modal_main">
<div class="note"> <?php
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $comment = "";
  } else {
    $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
  }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>


<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<div id="name">Task Name:<textarea name="title" rows="1.8" cols="20" style="margin-top: 50px"><?php echo $tit;?></textarea></div>
<textarea name="note" rows="15" cols="90" style="margin-top: 20px" placeholder="Note"><?php echo $not;?></textarea>
  <br><br>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submitted" value="Submit">
   <?php
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","task");
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $message=$_POST['note'];
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $qw='UPDATE note SET title = $title, note = $message';
    mysqli_query($con,$qw);
    $r="SELECT * FROM note";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $r);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if($row['title']==$_POST['title']){
    header("location:hh.php");
    }
    else{
    echo 'Title already exist!';
    }

}
}
?>
</form>




<img src="i783wQYjrKQ.png" class="close" style="line-height: 12px;
     margin-top: 1px;
     margin-right: 2px;
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     right:0;">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ask one question at the time please

Comment: `title = $title, note = $message` i dont think so, title and message will be used without quotes

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: do you think, it will work `$qw='UPDATE note SET title = $title, note = $message';`

Comment: yes, what should I do, or is it $qw='UPDATE note SET title = $tit, note = $not'; ?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a quick look at the code, you are leaving yourself wide open to a SQL injection attack.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","task");
        $qi = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT 'title', 'note' FROM note WHERE id = ".$_GET['id']);

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qi))
        $tit = $row['title'];
        $not = $row['note'];
    }
?>
```

I'd look at using PHP PDO library to safe guard against using values passed in from a web page directly in SQL code.

I'd use something more akin to:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'task';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
try {
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT title, note FROM note WHERE id = :id');
$stmt->execute(['id' => $_GET['id']]);
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$tit = $row['title'];
$not = $row['note'];
```

Obviously the connection details etc would be held in a separate external file such that they don't have to be included with every PHP file where DB access is required.